# How do I make a Primary Key read-only in Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

When using Fluent NHinbernate How do I make a PK Read only I tried to make it internal on the setter but I get this:

> ---->
>   NHibernate.InvalidProxyTypeException :
>   The following types may not be used as
>   proxies: Domain.Address: method
>   set_AddressId should be
>   'public/protected virtual' or
>   'protected internal virtual'

my mapping looks like:

```
Id(x => x.AddressId).GeneratedBy.Identity();
```

any Idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property AddressId should be made protected and virtual, eg:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public virtual int AddressId { get; protected set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make all methods and properties virtual. Ex.

```
public virtual int AddressId {get; private set;}
```

It all depends on what your line of inheritance and such is. The reason for declaring it virtual is the same as mocking a class. NHibernate needs to be able to override all the properties for lazy loading.